# C++ remove standard features

Tags: c++

Is it possible to remove standard features from C++

```
//Undefine some function from the standard like classes 
class someclass
{
    someclass(){
       //Whatever       
   }
};
```

then get the error

> "class undeclared identifier"

Comment: I am wondering why would you want to do that

Comment: Let me get this straight: do you want to remove/disable standard library functions? If so, why? I cannot think of any good reason to do this.

Comment: @CInCout just for fun

Comment: Sure.  Get the source code for an open-source compiler like GNU - https://gcc.gnu.org/  .  Edit the source to remove the features you don't want.  Build.  All done!

Comment: @Dave S would it be possible using a closed source compiler like Visual C++

Comment: The standard is not a supermarket.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I recommend it but you *can* use pre-processor macros to undefine anything you want.

If you compile the program below, you will get lots of errors.

```
#define vector 
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   vector<int> a;
}
```

You don't need the `#define vector` in the file. You can define it in the command used to invoke the compiler.

---

Note that using the above trick makes your program subject to undefined behavior:

From [the C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/reserved.names):

> **17.6.4.3 Reserved names**
>
> ...
>
> 2 If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined.
>
> **17.6.4.3.1 Macro names** [macro.names]
>
> 1 A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not `#define` or `#undef` names declared in any standard library header.
>
> 2 A translation unit shall not `#define` or `#undef` names lexically identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table [[tab:identifiers.special]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/lex.name#tab:identifiers.special), or to the [*attribute-tokens*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.attr.grammar#nt:attribute-token) described in [[dcl.attr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.attr).

Comment: 17.6.4.3.1 Macro names §2 A translation unit shall not `#define` or `#undef` names lexically identical to keywords...